# Minimum field required to tear up a conducting uncharged thin walled sphere

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, conductors

[image: Problem statement]

This problem is from the problem book of S.S. Krotov published in 1988. The problem number is 3.7. I was able to kind of understand the solution in the back of the book. I have presented one of the popular solutions which can be found online.

**Solution:** Since all the charge given to a conductor resides on its surface and the unoccupied cavity has a zero net field, essentially the behaviour of this thin walled sphere is the same as a solid conducting uniform sphere. Now, inside a conductor the field is zero. Thus, to create zero field, the sphere acquires a surface charge configuration of $\sigma = \sigma_0 cos\theta$ such that $E_0 = \frac{\sigma}{3\epsilon_0}$. Now, if we consider a patch of area $dS$ on the sphere, we can write the electrostatic force on the patch: $dF$ = $\frac{\sigma^2}{2\epsilon_0} * dS$ directed perpendicular to the surface. We can observe from here that the force $F$ is directly proportional to ${E_0}^2 * S^2$ and we can proceed now. The rest is trivial and not really necessary for answering my doubt.

**Doubt:** What is this force $dF$ the result of? Is it due to the electric field $E_0$ or does the reverse field $-E_0$ which is generated inside the sphere until the field inside becomes zero, have some role in it? I have seen the derivation of $dF$ or $F$ (basically the electrostatic pressure) in an arbitrary conductor under electric field, however, I am unable to figure out how we would calculate this value of $dF$ = $\frac{\sigma^2}{2\epsilon_0} * dS$ in this particular scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field $\frac{\sigma(r)}{2 \epsilon_{0}}$ is the field felt by a small patch of surface charge on the conductor, caused due to everything; the external $E_{0} $ and the remaining charges that gets induced.

No matter whatever situation you give me, if I have a conductor, the force experienced by a patch at any point is equal to $\frac{\sigma(r)}{2 \epsilon_{0}}$. This can be shown simply from gauss' law; the field immediately above a $\sigma(r)$ patch is $\frac{\sigma(r)}{\epsilon_{0}}$, and when you're infinitely close to this $\sigma(r)$ patch, one can treat it like an infinite sheet charge and conclude it's contribution to the field immediately above it is $\frac{\sigma(r)}{2 \epsilon_{0}}$. Therefore the net contribution, being $\frac{\sigma(r)}{ \epsilon_{0}}$ comes from this plate immediately below ($\frac{\sigma(r)}{2 \epsilon_{0}}$) and everything else. Therefore field at that point dur to everything else, comes to be $\frac{\sigma(r)}{2 \epsilon_{0}}$, which is approximately the field at the point of the $\sigma(r) $ patch, so we say the patch experiences a field $\frac{\sigma(r)}{2 \epsilon_{0}}$.

This is the net field felt by the patch. Whether the cancellation field does something or not, we don't care, the net field inside the sphere is unambiguously $0$.

Comment: This clarified a lot. I understood these points, correct me if I'm wrong:-  1. Electric field just outside the dS area patch will be $\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$. This electric field will be due to the patch and the rest of the universe (including the conductor) 2. There is no electric field inside the spherical conductor. 3. Electric field on any patch(whether charge density is -ve or +ve) will be perpendicular to surface and $E_{ext} = E_{patch} = \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$. 4. The cancelling field generated inside for a short time to cancel out $E_{ext}$ has no effect on pressure.

Comment: @arthur , your first and second inferences are correct, but the third one isn't(or maybe you made a typo). The field immediately outside any patch is due to the patch itself, and the rest of the world: the field due to the patch is $\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon}$, and net field is $\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon}$, hence field due to the rest of the universe is $\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon}$. This is the force felt by the patch (patch can't interact with itself) and this field on the patch is  $\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon}$

Comment: Yeah I made a typo in the 3rd point. Could you please provide a proof for the 3rd point in this specific case? Basically, I am having trouble understanding what will the $E_{ext}$ field will be the result of? Since the sphere is half negatively charged and half positively charged, we will have the external field which is mentioned in the problem $E_0$, so will the field due to everything else be a mixture of this $E_0$ and the cancelling field as well?? The cancelling field will be directed opposite inside the conductor because field lines move from +ve to -ve charges, i'm confuse

Comment: Basically, could you please provide a proof for the electric field just outside the patch $E = \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$ in this specific case (in this case, we have a conducting sphere having -ve charge density of one half and +ve charge density on other half and $\sigma$ = $\sigma_0 * cos\theta$ and we also have an external field $E_0$ directed horizontally along the $+x$ direction)?

Comment: @Arthur the external field $E_{0}$ causes a charge separation, which produces a $\sigma(\vec x)$ on the surface of the sphere, and the field **on** the patch is due to $E_{0}$ and the field created by the $\sigma (\vec x) $ everywhere except the patch $dS$. I suggest you stop worrying about the cancellation field, for it is merely the field produced by the $\sigma$ in some way or the other. Rather, it's much simpler to just think about the fields and their sources. And, your question was regarding the clarification for writing $df= \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_{0}} dq $ which I think is clear

Comment: @Arthur , my statement that the force experienced by a patch on a conductor is general, and works for all situations, not just this specific one. The proof is a very simple application of gauss law to deduce that for any general, random surface,  at a given point, (say $\hat n$ is the normal at this point), $$\vec E_{above} - \vec E_{below} = \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_{0}} \hat n$$ (hint, draw a wafer thin Gaussian surface on a random sheet of charge, make some logical approximations). If you are not able to derive it, textbooks like Griffiths do so, consult them

Comment: Actually, I have seen the proofs present in Griffiths and Purcell. However, in those situations they have assumed a conducting sphere with a +ve charge on the whole surface and there's no externally directed electric field (which is present in our case) and in that situation I have no problem understanding the derivation. These textbooks assume the field due to rest of the universe to be in the same direction as the patch. However, in this problem the field is directed in $+x$ direction and the patch is at an angle $\theta$ to the externally directed field. And, the charge density is not same.

Comment: I suggest you look again these proofs, for they don't assume any shell, they assume very general situations, of general surface charge distributions. This example you are giving here is a special case, and hence obviously the formula for $df$ will work in this example. Whether there is an external field or not doesn't matter, for gauss law holds always. If you still have doubts, forget that I said any of this, draw a very thin gauss surface at a point, and deduce that $$E_{\perp}^{above} - E_{\perp}^{below} =\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_{0}}$$ and $$E^{above}_{\parallel} = E^{below}_{\parallel}$$

Comment: Thanks! i need more characters

Answer (score 0):

$E_o$ is the minimum external electric field required to polarize the spherical conductor with half the sphere acquiring negative charge and other part gets positive charge on its outermost surface.
Electric field attracts negative charge density and repels the other charge density to stretch sphere and break it apart, at value, just greater than $E_o$.